# How to get XML values in SQL statement?

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

Below is the XML TAG, From where i need to take the values and form it as a SQL OUTPUT and i am facing some problem ,

```
<xml>
    <Channel>
        <Program id="1" category="A">
            <name>PraMatino</name>
            <Bin>
                <Date>1/1/2020</Date>
                <Date>1/1/2020</Date>
            </Bin>
            <Player>
                <Pla>Rajesh</Pla>
                <Pla>Suman</Pla>
            </Player>
            <Television>
                <HostDeails>2/9/2020</HostDeails>
                <HostDeails>MALE</HostDeails>
                <HostDeails>Colour</HostDeails>
            </Television>
            <addresses>
                <address>
                    <address1>No 10</address1>
                    <city>Chennai</city>
                    <country>IN</country>
                    <ProductName>Lavender</ProductName>
                </address>
                <address>
                    <address1>N0 72</address1>
                    <city>Sanagoor Road</city>
                    <postalCode>641006</postalCode>
                </address>
                <address>
                    <address1>Old No 10/ New No 3</address1>
                    <city>Madurai</city>
                    <country>IN</country>
                    <ProductName>Lavender</ProductName>
                </address>
                <address>
                    <address1>N0 98</address1>
                    <city>BridhSanagoor Road</city>
                    <country>SriLanka</country>
                    <postalCode>641006</postalCode>
                </address>
            </addresses>
        </Program>
        <Program id="25" category="B">
            <name>Rahman</name>
            <Bin>
                <Date>10/1/2020</Date>
                <Date>1/12/1989</Date>
            </Bin>
            <Player>
                <Pla>Paul</Pla>
                <Pla>Right</Pla>
            </Player>
            <Television>
                <HostDeails>5/7/2021</HostDeails>
                <HostDeails>MALE</HostDeails>
                <HostDeails>Colour</HostDeails>
            </Television>
            <addresses>
                <address>
                    <address1>S7</address1>
                    <city>Coimbatire</city>
                    <country>IN</country>
                    <ProductName>Lavender</ProductName>
                </address>
                <address>
                    <address1>Sai Akshya Appartment</address1>
                    <city>Sanagoor Road</city>
                    <postalCode>631009</postalCode>
                </address>
                <address>
                    <address1> No 3</address1>
                    <city>Thenkaasi</city>
                    <ProductName>Lavender</ProductName>
                </address>
                <address>
                    <address1>N0 98</address1>
                    <city>BridhSanagoor Road</city>
                    <country>SriLanka</country>
                    <postalCode>641006</postalCode>
                </address>
            </addresses>
        </Program>
    </Channel>
</xml>
```

How to query above XML into below SQL select statement ?

i could able to achieve for the "ADDRESS1" and "CITY" but if i try to include "ID" and "CATEGORY" tags with respective "ADDRESSES", its not working as expected. Kindly share your thoughts

[image: Out put]
Thank you

Comment: You need to specify your database vendor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify your database vendor. Please try the following SQL. It is for MS SQL Server. It simulates one-to-many relationship inside XML via `CROSS APPLY` clause and different aliases.

> SQL

```
DECLARE @xml XML = 
N'<xml>
    <Channel>
        <Program id="1" category="A">
            <name>PraMatino</name>
            <Bin>
                <Date>1/1/2020</Date>
                <Date>1/1/2020</Date>
            </Bin>
            <Player>
                <Pla>Rajesh</Pla>
                <Pla>Suman</Pla>
            </Player>
            <Television>
                <HostDeails>2/9/2020</HostDeails>
                <HostDeails>MALE</HostDeails>
                <HostDeails>Colour</HostDeails>
            </Television>
            <addresses>
                <address>
                    <address1>No 10</address1>
                    <city>Chennai</city>
                    <country>IN</country>
                    <ProductName>Lavender</ProductName>
                </address>
                <address>
                    <address1>N0 72</address1>
                    <city>Sanagoor Road</city>
                    <postalCode>641006</postalCode>
                </address>
                <address>
                    <address1>Old No 10/ New No 3</address1>
                    <city>Madurai</city>
                    <country>IN</country>
                    <ProductName>Lavender</ProductName>
                </address>
                <address>
                    <address1>N0 98</address1>
                    <city>BridhSanagoor Road</city>
                    <country>SriLanka</country>
                    <postalCode>641006</postalCode>
                </address>
            </addresses>
        </Program>
        <Program id="25" category="B">
            <name>Rahman</name>
            <Bin>
                <Date>10/1/2020</Date>
                <Date>1/12/1989</Date>
            </Bin>
            <Player>
                <Pla>Paul</Pla>
                <Pla>Right</Pla>
            </Player>
            <Television>
                <HostDeails>5/7/2021</HostDeails>
                <HostDeails>MALE</HostDeails>
                <HostDeails>Colour</HostDeails>
            </Television>
            <addresses>
                <address>
                    <address1>S7</address1>
                    <city>Coimbatire</city>
                    <country>IN</country>
                    <ProductName>Lavender</ProductName>
                </address>
                <address>
                    <address1>Sai Akshya Appartment</address1>
                    <city>Sanagoor Road</city>
                    <postalCode>631009</postalCode>
                </address>
                <address>
                    <address1>No 3</address1>
                    <city>Thenkaasi</city>
                    <ProductName>Lavender</ProductName>
                </address>
                <address>
                    <address1>N0 98</address1>
                    <city>BridhSanagoor Road</city>
                    <country>SriLanka</country>
                    <postalCode>641006</postalCode>
                </address>
            </addresses>
        </Program>
    </Channel>
</xml>';

SELECT prog.c.value('@id','INT') AS id
    , prog.c.value('@category','CHAR(1)') AS category
    , addr.c.value('(address1/text())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS address1
    , addr.c.value('(city/text())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS city
FROM @xml.nodes('/xml/Channel/Program') AS prog(c)
    CROSS APPLY prog.c.nodes('addresses/address') AS addr(c);
```

> Output

```
+----+----------+-----------------------+--------------------+
| id | category |       address1        |        city        |
+----+----------+-----------------------+--------------------+
|  1 | A        | No 10                 | Chennai            |
|  1 | A        | N0 72                 | Sanagoor Road      |
|  1 | A        | Old No 10/ New No 3   | Madurai            |
|  1 | A        | N0 98                 | BridhSanagoor Road |
| 25 | B        | S7                    | Coimbatire         |
| 25 | B        | Sai Akshya Appartment | Sanagoor Road      |
| 25 | B        | No 3                  | Thenkaasi          |
| 25 | B        | N0 98                 | BridhSanagoor Road |
+----+----------+-----------------------+--------------------+
```